# Extend encrypted LVM

Tags: encryption, lvm

I want to add 400GB to my encrypted  LVM added as home directory. This is the way it looks now:

```
sda               8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0  94,1M  0 part  /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0  55,8G  0 part  
  └─main        254:0    0  55,8G  0 crypt 
    ├─main-swap 254:1    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─main-root 254:2    0  51,8G  0 lvm   /
```

How can I add the remaining 400GB to sda2/main/main-home?

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands (just a sketch, add the device paths):

```
lvresize -l +100%FREE
cryptsetup resize
resize2fs # assuming ext*
```

Comment: Thanks for answering that 2 years ago! I've just found it very useful!

Comment: @Ginger why not just use KDE Partition Manager 3.0 these days? It can resize LVM LV independent of fs used... And even LVM encrypted with LUKS...